# How to accelerate a greensock timeline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgb(107,127,125);
    border: 1px solid rgb(174,77,61);
    display: block;
 }
```

JS

```
var tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.staggerTo($(".box"), 1, {x: "200px"}, 0.4);
```

I want to gradually increase the speed at which the boxes are animated to the right.
i e:

1. box animation duration = 1s
2. box = 0.8s
3. box = 0.78s, etc.

I know I could loop through the boxes and specify a different duration for each, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Is it possible to apply a predefined ease like

```
ease: Bounce.easeOut
```

to the timeline itself, not to each tween in the timeline?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bwzvyctk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `timeScale()` to accelerate the timeline after each stagger. Here's [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/bwzvyctk/3/).

```
function tweenComplete() {
  scale += 1;
  tl.timeScale(scale);
}
```